# Is there an efficient way to create a map from an array which stores count of keys in Typescript?

Tags: arrays, typescript, dictionary, counter

Suppose I have an array a, `a = ['John', 'John', 'Bill', 'John', 'Bill ', 'Sally']`, is there an easy way to produce a map, m, that produces the following using Typescript, `m = {{'John', 3}, {'Bill', 2}, {'Sally', 1}}` ?

I've been stuck on producing an efficient way without the use of a loop. Python for example has the Counter function which one can use to quickly produce a dictionary with every key in a list along with its count.

Does anyone happen to know if Typescript has a built-in function that solves this problem, or will I have to ultimately use a loop?

Comment: Any implementation would probably also use a loop ,no matter what it will still be O(n).

Comment: a.forEach(val=> count[val] = (count[val] || 0) + 1); this is my current implementation. You are right in the sense that either way the time-complexity will be the same, but I was just looking for something that would hopefully require less of a complex line to write compared to what I have.

Comment: `{{'John', 3}, {'Bill', 2}, {'Sally', 1}}` is not valid TypeScript code. Could you provide a [mre] where the only issues present are the ones you're trying to solve?  And oof, `"Bill"` and `"Bill "` are two different strings.

Comment: There's no "built-in" function that does this. Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/NBjlnN) meet your needs? If so I could write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?